# Matlab coloured checkerboard

Tags: matlab, colors, rgb, psychtoolbox

I'm using the Matlab `checkerboard` function to create a checkerboard. I'm interested in having the checkerboard as stripes (rather than checks) which I have figured out. I also want to change the colour of the stripes so that it's red and white or red and pink rather than black and white. I don't understand how to do this.

In the Matlab checkerboard function, black is defined as `zeros(n)` where `n` is the size and because the colour code for black in Matlab is [0 0 0], this works. But I don't get how to set this for it to produce red coloured tiles or stripes.

I have tried

```
   red = repmat([1 0 0], 81,27)
```

to get red stripes for a checkerboard that I want with 81 squares. This produces an `81 x 81` matrix that looks like:

```
  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 .... 1 0 0 
  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 .... 1 0 0 
  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 .... 1 0 0 
  .
  .
  .
  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 .... 1 0 0
```

And it isn't red, it's just black and white stripes of varying thickness.

Can anyone help?!

Comment: You can use `imagesc` for plotting and change the `colormap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `imagesc` to plot, and `colormap` to change colors,

```
red = repmat([1 0 0], 81, 27);
cmap(1,:) = [1 0 0];
cmap(2,:) = [0 0 0];
imagesc(red);
colormap(cmap);
```

This should give you,

[image: checkerboard with red stripes]